# Boot-Repair created too many grub menu entries for Windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I recently installed Ubuntu in dual boot along with Windows 10 on an HP laptop. Initially I was unable to boot up Windows using grub as selecting the Windows options would just loop back to grub.

Then I performed a boot repair, and all these extra options showed up in the grub menu.

I'm able to open up Windows using "Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi" option, but not using the standard option of "Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda1).

How do I reduce these entries and why can't I boot Windows using the latter option?

Here's an image of grub. The first option is Ubuntu:

[image: grub - the 1st option is Ubuntu]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove old kernel versions to clean up the boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu)

Comment: It isn't really a duplicate of that. Mine doesn't show Linux kernel entries. Plus the point that I'm unable to boot Windows using the boot manager option.

Comment: Wow, you're quick!  You should only accept *after* you've tried out an answer, but this one will surely help!!!  **;-)**  Also, did I mention you should really take a back-up before starting or be *really, really* careful about what you delete?!

Comment: Using GRUB Customizer, as Fabby suggests, is likely to help. As to why one option is working and another isn't, we'd need to see the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file from your system. My suspicion is that the non-working entry is designed for BIOS-based systems, but yours is clearly EFI-based, so a BIOS-mode option is a (literal) non-starter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Windows is off-topic here,** <s>but the answer is that this is very old technology and the boot sector is only 512 bytes, so it's not big enough to hold everything we would like it to hold.</s>

To easily add and remove entries from grub all on your own, please:

1. **Take a full system back-up of your entire computer including the other OSes using [CloneZilla Live](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php)**
2. No, I wasn't kidding!  Take a *full system back-up* first! **:-)**
3. Whenever someone tells you to [install a PPA](https://askubuntu.com/a/575161/344926) be very cautious, do your own research if this is what you really want and only then continue
4. Install [grub-customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer) by executing the following commands:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install grub-customizer
   ```
5. Start `grub-customizer` and customize the hell out of it:
   [image]
6. If you run into serious trouble, restore your system back-up.

Comment: You have a delicate style in answers, and even in your comments. Honestly I really wonder why not everyone marks the correct and useful answer as an answer, frustrates me but I never asked for it. I may copy your comments and paste it after my answers 

Comment: I just gave you a plus one on a different `grub` question on hiding boot menu. However in this case "I'm relatively certain" the answer I just posted on this thread is the correct one. It's happened to me twice now and the repair method is flawless each time.

Comment: FTR I've upvoted this answer too. Last year's comment may have been misconstrued.

Answer (score 13):

Every time I've run `boot-repair` it adds a **5** extra Windows boot options to my main `grub` menu that do not work. In your case it has added **11** extra entries!

### `grub.cfg` shows the problem

The secret can be found within `/etc/grub/grub.cfg` file:

```bash
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/25_custom ###
    menuentry "Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root D656-F2A8
chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}

menuentry "Windows Boot UEFI loader" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root D656-F2A8
chainloader (${root})/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
}

menuentry "EFI/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root D656-F2A8
chainloader (${root})/EFI/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi
}

menuentry "Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi sda1" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 9478-B6E2
chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}

menuentry "Windows Boot UEFI loader sda1" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 9478-B6E2
chainloader (${root})/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
### END /etc/grub.d/25_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/nvme0n1p2)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-D656-F2A8' {
    savedefault
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  D656-F2A8
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root D656-F2A8
    fi
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-9478-B6E2' {
    savedefault
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
    set root='hd0,gpt1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  9478-B6E2
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9478-B6E2
    fi
    chainloader /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
```

The section `30_os-prober` contains the "good" Windows `grub` menu entries you want to keep. Section `25_custom` contains the bogus entries created by `boot-repair`. You can't edit the grub configuration file because it will simply be overwritten the next time `update-grub` is run.

---

### Section `25_custom` was created by Boot Repair

On my system:

```bash
$ locate 25_custom
/boot/efi/boot-repair/log/20171111_224241/nvme0n1p5/25_custom
/boot/efi/boot-repair/log/20171208_030854/nvme0n1p5/25_custom
/etc/grub.d/25_custom
```

Take a look at the extra Windows options that were setup (and don't work):

```bash
$ cat /boot/efi/boot-repair/log/20171208_030854/nvme0n1p5/25_custom
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0

menuentry "Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root D656-F2A8
chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}

menuentry "Windows Boot UEFI loader" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root D656-F2A8
chainloader (${root})/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
}

menuentry "EFI/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root D656-F2A8
chainloader (${root})/EFI/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi
}

menuentry "Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi sda1" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 9478-B6E2
chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}

menuentry "Windows Boot UEFI loader sda1" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 9478-B6E2
chainloader (${root})/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
```

These are the erroneous entries `boot-repair` created in `/etc/grub.d/25_custom` that were subsequently compiled into `\boot\grub\grub.cfg`.

---

### Reverse Boot Repair's change to `25_custom`

Use `sudo -H gedit /etc/grub.d/25_custom` and delete everything except the first three lines:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
```

- The file now contains two lines with text and one blank line.
- Save the file.
- Run `sudo update-grub`.
- Reboot.

Now your menu is no longer bloated with five bogus Windows menu entries that don't work.

#### Double-check there are three lines in `25_custom`

Run this command and verify `25_custom` has three lines:

```bash
$ wc /etc/grub.d/25_custom
      3       6      30
#     ^       ^       ^
#     |       |       +--- Number of characters
#     |       +----------- Number of words
#     +------------------- Number of lines
```

I added the `#` comments to decipher `wc` (word count) output.

Comment: I can't downvote my own answer nor delete it, but I can upvote you...  :)  Beware that a GUI solution will always get more votes than a text-based solution though the text-based solution is generally more exact (=technically better)

Comment: As I just got an upvote on my answer, I'm surprised to see that your non-GUI has racked up more votes than mine!  **Good job!**

Comment: @Fabby Thanks. I just gave yours an up-vote too :)

Comment: I might be late in asking but...why is 25_custom needed at all? Why are those 3 lines needed?

Comment: @poomerang It's the natural order of an empty configuration file in grub's world. It's easier to conform than to rebel.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix asking is free of charge though :)