# How to avoid loss of dual boot menu due to Windows 10 update

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, 18.04, windows, windows-10

The dual boot menu always gets by passed after Windows 10 automatically updates. Is there any work around this? It's a pain to always recover the grub menu. Last time it occurred, I did all the magic in the book and yet it did not get recover. I have a new system and how to avoid this happening in the first place?

Comment: I simply run `boot-repair` and then remove the 5 or 6 extra Windows entries from grub: [Boot Repair created too many Grub menu entries for Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938633/boot-repair-created-too-many-grub-menu-entries-for-windows/1022700#1022700)

Comment: Microsoft Windows Updates are a pain. They twiddle with the boot parameters in Windows, thereby bypassing GRUB and booting directly into Windows. `boot-repair` won't solve this problem. You have to use `bcdedit` from Windows to fix it. Some Microsoft updates even wipe Ubuntu partitions!

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix please see my comment. `boot-repair` won't solve this problem.

Comment: @heynnema OP just said "I did all the magic in the book" which implies `bcdedit` was already done. But yes for myself `boot-repair` does the trick and haven't had to resort to `bcdedit` or any other magic spells. I think the OP needs to clarify all the magic tricks performed with exact commands used and copy and pasted output (if there is any errors).

Comment: Yet I did bcedit, boot-repair, disk checks. None of it helped. But I could see that the partition still existed. I had a mounting problem with the said partition though. I am not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way is to have one OS in virturalbox, or have two separate hard drives(or two computers), removing the one with Ubuntu on it during windows updates.  I had asked similar question few months ago about protecting linux partition from windows.

Comment: This is the path I followed for critical Windows applications on an Ubuntu host. Paired with regular backups, it has been highly reliable and recoverable for years.While it requires a purchased Windows key, I found it money well spent. And I can use Windows and Ubuntu *simultaneously*