# How to make grub menu appear instead grub minimal bash-like in booting?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

This keep happening when I install the Ubuntu as a dual boot for my laptop. I get a black that appears when booting with the following messages.

```
Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported.   
For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. 
Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.  


grub>  
grub>  
grub>  
grub>  
grub>  
grub>  
grub>  
grub>  
grub>
```

I have to enter these commands like this:

```
grub> set prefix=(hd0,msdos6)/boot/grub/ 
grub> insmod normal 
grub> normal
```

And the GRUB menu appears. How to make my GRUB menu appear without having to type those command at my GRUB prompts?

I tried `sudo grub-install` and it give me this error message.

[image]

I tried to check if i have chosen the right disk, which come two possibilities, `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda6`, but neither of these two works, and they gave the same error message.

`/dev/sda1/`

[image]

`/dev/sda6`

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Note:** If you can't boot Ubuntu at all, use a Live USB to boot Ubuntu, select "Try before installing" and perform steps below.

---

After booting the hard way, open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and install [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
```

Then type `boot-repair` and a menu will appear:

[image: boot-repair menu.png]

Select the recommended option.

If your system boots normally after recommended repair great. If not post the link to the problems reported.

---

#### Caveats

On some systems this annoyance can occur:

- [Boot-Repair created too many grub menu entries for Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938633/boot-repair-created-too-many-grub-menu-entries-for-windows/1022700#1022700)

If this happens to you, visit the link for a solution.

Comment: Can someone give this man a medal?

Answer (score 6):

Once booted into Ubuntu run the following command:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

This assumes that `/dev/sda` is your disk that matches `(hd0,msdos6)` in your grub command, which it likely is. You can run a graphical program like `gnome-disks` or `gparted` to confirm it's the correct disk.

The command `grub-install` will detect any partitions and re-install your bootloader so it can find the bootable partitions.

Comment: didnt work, see my updated question.

Comment: You always install grub to a drive like sda, almost never to a partition like sda1 or sda6.

Answer (score 3):

First step would be, after logging into Ubuntu, in Terminal type:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

(or `/dev/whatever-harddisk`)

wait until installation of grub is finished, then ...

Second step would be, to update grub with:

```
sudo update-grub2
```

wait until updating of `grub-config-file` is finished.

```
reboot
```

Then restart of ubuntu should be no problem and you pass by into
Ubuntu gdm screen or lightdm screen for desktop again.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it is actually due to having the installer and the OS in the same computer but in different disks and you are booting from the OS. It can not properly detect which is the OS and therefore gives you a GRUB menu. This mostly happens in Android x86. If this happens, please eject the installer disk. If it still happens even if you have ejected it or the installer disk is not present, use the other solution here.