# How to configur grub2

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I can't say I'm new to Ubuntu, but I'm still a noob. I have recently installed a SSD in the place of my notebook's CD drive. Then I have installed Kubuntu 18.10 and kept my HD with Windows untouched (something tells me I'm not going to load Windows so soon).

Now when I boot the computer, GRUB shows a command line, if I type 'exit' then it shows the "normal" menu with Ubuntu and Windows. I have searched the problem, but what I have found either semeed a little different from my problem or I lacked the confidence to follow the solution.

I would like to know how i could configure GRUB so it goes straight to the menu screen.

I have tried this https://askubuntu.com/a/1105737/935425 but it didn't make da bash like grub go away, it have just grown the list of possible boots with UEFI options.

Comment: Can you post the link to your `boot-repair` report?

Comment: I have found these two files, I don't know which one you want http://lia.ufc.br/~filho/Boot-Info_20190425_1228.txt http://lia.ufc.br/~filho/boot-repair.log

Comment: When you run `boot-repair` it gives you option of listing report on the internet so it will begin with `//HTTPS...`

Comment: I could not find anything like that. Maybe I did not take that option.

Comment: It may also begin with something like `www.ubuntu.paste.bin` It's been so long since I've used boot repair I forget the exact name. Basically though the report is saved to the internet and you can paste that link into your question so everyone can see it.

Answer (score 0):

I went to Boot menu and turned out there were two boot enter for the same HD, the one with Ubuntu, so I changed their order in boot and resolved.

### EDIT

It didn't work. I'm still in the same point. I just gave up.

Answer (score -1):

Configure GRUB2 Boot Loader settings
Warning: The default configuration file for GRUB2 is /boot/grub/grub.cfg. You shouldn’t edit or modify this file, unless you are much familiar with GRUB2. This is the main file to boot into the Linux OS. If you do anything wrong with this file, then you will be surely end up with broken system. So, Don’t touch this file!

All settings related to the GRUB2 will be stored in /etc/default/grub file. Whatever the changes you made in this file will be reflected to the GRUB2.

you found configurations down below this website

https://www.ostechnix.com/configure-grub-2-boot-loader-settings-ubuntu-16-04/