# Computer boots to GNU Grub after every restart

Tags: boot, grub2

When i restart my computer for any reason it automatically boots to GNU Grub screen. I then have to type `reboot` and then go to my BIOS and select the Ubuntu install and then it boots just fine. Its not that big of a deal. just makes me want to restart my computer less often. not sure if there is something i can do to fix that. I do not have windows on my computer only Ubuntu.

Here is a picture for my issue.

[image]

It has been 6 Days since I added the screenshots of my issue, and I havent gotten any responses. I have been unable to figure this issue out. I tried the one answer in the comments but it didnt help.

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot or photo of the screen to imgur.com and then edit the question and add the link to the picture? I don't know what you mean by "go to BIOS and select Ubuntu install." Again a picture will be helpful.

Comment: @Brett Plemons Was it working before or is it like this since installation of your actual Ubuntu version?

Comment: It's a good idea to run boot repair first before anything else: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104855/how-to-make-grub-menu-appear-instead-grub-minimal-bash-like-in-booting

Answer (score 1):

1. Possibly you have two or more hard disks in the PC and Bios has the other one as first disk. Please change that priority in bios OR interchange the sata data cable of the hdds.
   or
2. Grub is not properly installed. Install grub (if Ubuntu is installed on partition `sda`)

   ```
   sudo grub-install /dev/sda
   sudo update-grub2
   ```

   Reboot.