# Fix conditional error of 'Operating System Not Found'

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2

My Ubuntu System(18.04 LTS) is just showing me like 'No Operating System Found' or 'Read Error' or Grub Error 'Unknown Error'. And also after I shutdown or switch on my system, some text is shown like command-line commands. I also tried typing `ls` but it didn't work and showed me an empty line in grub rescue mode. Also, it comes and then goes after some time. So please help me.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. It could be you are suffering from a disk failure or failing disk/sdd.  I would check your drive's inbuilt diagnostics.  The safest way to do this is via booting your system with a 'live' media such as Ubuntu install media (any version), and using `smartctl` or `gnome-disks` (the second is a GUI utility which is easier to operate; the first is command line & provides more detail but takes more effort to read). This may be helpful - https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-ssd-or-hdd-on-current-versions-of-ubuntu-1

Comment: The easiest first thing to try boot-repair but I'm not sure it will work in this case: [How to make grub menu appear instead grub minimal bash-like in booting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104855/how-to-make-grub-menu-appear-instead-grub-minimal-bash-like-in-booting/1105737#1105737)