# Not having windows as an option

Tags: dual-boot

I can boot into ubuntu only after I enter the "advanced options for ubuntu" and go into recovery mode where i need to select use the "repair broken packeges" option. The problem is that I want to boot on windows 10 but it doesn't apper as an option on grub. I have tried using terminal commands but when I reboot the computer it just crashes in a purple screen and I can't do anything else than shutting down my laptop. After shutting it down, the grub us not updated and I have to do the steps all over again. I would very much appreciate if someone could help me. Thanks!

And btw I don't mind having to uninstall ubuntu in order to get back the option of windows 10, or having to uninstall grub.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Comment: See the duplicate above but note that `boot-repair` is the easiest first option to try: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104855/how-to-make-grub-menu-appear-instead-grub-minimal-bash-like-in-booting/1105737#1105737

Answer (score 0):

**Since you need Recovery Mode, lets first check your file system for errors.**

For 17.10 or older...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

For 18.04 or newer...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**After repairing any errors using fsck, if that doesn't solve the problem, try boot-repair. See...**

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Plugging in the live usb does nothing. It just keeps showing me these options: "ubuntu", "advanced options for ubuntu" and "system setup". Is there anything i can do in bios?

Comment: @CodrutPlaiasu  It doesn't sound like you're actually booting to the Live USB, as it should give options to include "Try Ubuntu without installing", and "Install Ubuntu". Are you able to recreate your USB, or maybe create a DVD?

Comment: after boot ubuntu without installation it just crashes. I can't give any commands to the terminal. What else could i try?

Comment: @CodrutPlaiasu on the GRUB menu, either on your main computer, or on the Ubuntu Live USB, do you see a memtest option?

Comment: so this is what i am doing: 1. Enter on System setup; 2. Press F9 to enter into "Boot device options";  3.Select "USB CD/DCD ROM Drive (UEFI) - USB CD/DVD Drive"; 4. Select "Try ubuntu without installing". I haven t seen the memtest option on the grub menu, where I have just 3 options: Ubuntu, Advanced options for Ubuntu and System setup. Should I try to install it again?

Comment: @CodrutPlaiasu and if you choose Advanced Options, can you get to the root prompt, or does it crash there? Do you have access to another computer where you can build USB's or burn DVDs?

Comment: if i choose advanced options from the gnu grub menu I get 4 options which start the same "ubuntu, with linux 4.18.0-25-generic" (2 of the have recovery mode written next ti them)

Comment: @CodrutPlaiasu choose recovery mode for the newest kernel. Then select root access. Then do the 18.04 version of fsck, starting at the fdisk command.

Comment: after I select fsck( check all file systems ) it tells me that it requires my filesystem to be in read-only mode. How can i change that?

Comment: @CodrutPlaiasu Sorry, maybe we misunderstood each other. You booted to the hard disk, and you can't run fsck from there, as you have 18.04 or newer. You need to boot to the Live USB and select "Try Ubuntu". Maybe you tried that and it crashed? Otherwise, just follow the instructions in the 2nd part of my answer.

Comment: i've selected "try ubuntu" and it just crashes

Comment: @CodrutPlaiasu you may have a hardware problem. Go to **https://www.memtest86.com/**, and download/run free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory.

Comment: is it a good idea to put a windows image on a usb and try to boot from that?

Comment: @CodrutPlaiasu no, lets just run memtest first.

Comment: @CodrutPlaiasu status please...