# I basically installed Ubuntu Desktop 19.04 and my computer will not work

Tags: system-installation, desktop-environments, error-handling

My computer only boots up to 2 option.
 1.
It shows only
`_`
 2.
Shows me GNU GRUB Version 2.02

What should I do now to fix this. On the BIOS it won't show my windows disk. And when I go to legacy mode and try the SSD which has my windows OS it just shows me option 1.

Comment: What happens when you pick **option 2.**:  `GNU GRUB Version 2.02`?

Comment: It just shows a basic command line, no ubuntu commands.

Comment: Boot with a live USB and see if this helps: [boot-repair](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104855/how-to-make-grub-menu-appear-instead-grub-minimal-bash-like-in-booting/1105737#1105737)