# GRUB menu not showing options in dual boot with Phoenix OS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit as my main OS on my HP laptop. I recently installed Phoenix-OS in dual-boot, but when I boot up my laptop the GRUB screen for OS selection is not showing. It boots into a purple screen which I believe is the GRUB menu, but there is nothing written on it or any options shown. This screen keeps showing for the exact amount of time I selected in GRUB customizer.

What can I do to get the proper GRUB menu?

Edited: So apparently, the grub decided to show up randomly when I click esc, but I can't do anything, the only key is esc, and I click it, "Minimal BASH-like editing is ......." show up with a kind of a terminal "grub>".
Now how can I resolve my issue ?

Comment: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: So, I think that the grub menu is configured, all good, but I don't see the menu or anything written on the screen ( just the purple background) and I can't choose anything just by navigating using keyboard, my best shot here is to find some other way to boot into the other OS using terminal or something

Comment: Boot Ubuntu USB live installer in live mode, add Boot-Repair and post link it gives for Summary Report.

Comment: Tom Brossman, it's different because I have to repair GRUB from Ubuntu, not from Windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make grub menu appear instead grub minimal bash-like in booting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104855/how-to-make-grub-menu-appear-instead-grub-minimal-bash-like-in-booting) **Note:** First you may have to boot with Live USB.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: [Youtube](https://youtu.be/-aSZTK6crW4)

Hope this helps.