# GRUB doesn't show up with Windows 8.1

Tags: boot, grub2

I have installed minutes ago Ubuntu 19.04 on my ASUS laptop (X540LJ) but when the computer boots up, it boot in Windows 8.1. How I can choose if boot up Windows or Ubuntu? (If you ask how I managed to boot up Ubuntu, I opened the Boot Menu and boot from Hard Drive.)

Comment: Try `boot-repair`: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104855/how-to-make-grub-menu-appear-instead-grub-minimal-bash-like-in-booting/1105737#1105737