# Booting from terminal

Tags: boot, command-line, grub2, busybox

What commands is it that I need to boot in from any terminal like busybox,grub, and original I need the example of how to do so from the terminals especially from busybox i,it's a but confusing for me and would like to learn how to .

I'm booting into Ubuntu and intrimids/busybox (not sure what name was) comes up instead of the GUI. I don't know how I messed up in making bootloader, as I used Rufus. On top of that it won't read as cd rom as I use it to fir apt-cdrom add or to load components.

Comment: Current Ubuntu versions (16.04, 18.04, and 19.04) do not need to have commands entered at the terminal to boot. The PC runs the Power On Self Test, GRUB launches, then starts the GNOME desktop environment. Do you wish to change from GNOME to Busybox https://busybox.net/FAQ.html#whatis temporarily or permanently? Please click [edit] and tell us what you want to have happen. Please don't use Add Comment; instead, use [edit].

Comment: That's the problem I'm booting into Ubuntu and intrimids/busybox (not sure what name was) comes up and I don't know how I messed up in making bootloader I used Rufus and on top of that it won't read as cd rom as I use it to fir apt-cdrom add or to load components

Comment: See if this helps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104855/how-to-make-grub-menu-appear-instead-grub-minimal-bash-like-in-booting/1104856

Answer (score 0):

At the terminal prompt, you can start your Desktop Environment with the command `startx`<kbd>Enter</kbd>.  Copy off everything you want to save to get it off the drive.

As to the LiveUSB you used to install Ubuntu, I would suggest recreating it after copying off all the files you need to preserve on that USB.   Redownload the version of Ubuntu you wish to use from https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours or https://ubuntu.com/download and [verify it was not corrupted in transit](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0).

Once verified, open [Rufus](https://rufus.ie) again; if it isn't version 3.8, I would download the current version and install that.

Boot selection should be set to **Disk or ISO image**.  Click on SELECT to the right of the Boot selection field then choose the ISO file you just verified.

Partition scheme should be **GPT**.

Quick format should be checked.

Create extended label and icon files should be checked.

Click START

When it completes, boot your Ubuntu PC from the Live USB you just created, and [reinstall Ubuntu](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0) (or the flavour you choose instead of vanilla Ubuntu).

When you reach  [6. Allocate disk space](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#5)  pick the option to erase the drive and (re)install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you didn't enable persistence in Rufus when you created your drive?

Because if you did, and you aren't using Ubuntu 19.10, then you will get into busybox, due to a bug in Ubuntu 19.04 and earlier that prevents persistent partitions from being properly mounted.

In other words, if you are using Ubuntu 18.04 or 19.04, and are using Rufus to create your drive, you should not enable persistence in Rufus for the time being.

Now, it is possible that the next update of 18.04 might backport the fix, so that it too will start to work with persistence at last. But until then, you should only enable persistence in Rufus if you are using Ubuntu 19.10 or later because, if not, all you will get during boot is a busybox prompt instead of the GUI...