# Windows 10 option in ubuntu grub not working

Tags: dual-boot, grub-legacy

I've been trying to dual boot Windows 10 / Ubuntu on my Lenovo Ideapad 320, so I first install Windows 10 ***(legacy)***, then installed Ubuntu 18.04 (and 17.04)***(also legacy)***.

In the process of installing, Ubuntu installed GRUB. Now after installing Ubuntu, when I restart my laptop, the pink-ish screen of Ubuntu appears with the GRUB, and there is a "Windows 10" option in the GRUB.

When I tap that "Windows 10" option, after some lights off & on, the GRUB appears again and I can't go back to Windows by any means. I've been stuck with this for 2 days, tried many times with no avail.

How do I get back my Windows Boot Loader or How can I go back to Windows? What seems to be the problem? I've Secure Boot disabled.

Comment: Try running boot-repair: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104855/how-to-make-grub-menu-appear-instead-grub-minimal-bash-like-in-booting

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 does not make it easy to dual boot. It uses fast start up which really is just hibernation and sets hibernation flag. Grub only boots working Windows and hibernation flag cannot be set. And Windows will keep turning on fast start up with updates. Also when Windows breaks or needs chkdsk, grub will not boot it.

And better to use UEFI as then you can always directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu.

But with BIOS you have to temporarily restore a Windows boot loader, fix Windows, if you can get to internal repair console, and then restore grub. If you still cannot boot Windows, you have to use your Windows repair flash drive or Windows installer that has a repair console.

Fast start up off.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions &

[Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

You will need to always have a Windows repair flash drive & your Ubuntu live installer flash drive to make BIOS type repairs. Good to have if UEFI boot, but not required every time Windows turns on fast start up as you can directly boot in UEFI boot menu.

If Boot-Repair sees the Windows boot partition, it may in advanced mode offer to install a Windows type boot loader - syslinux to MBR. See tab on MBR options. Also boot flag must be on Windows primary NTFS partition with boot files, often a small 100MB partition not otherwise seen in Windows.

https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

In Windows it is the fixMBR command to restore Windows boot loader.

[Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)