# 18.4 stopped booting

Tags: boot, 18.04, 13.04

18.4 fails to boot even in safe mode with a final note of
Failure: file system check of root filesystem failed
The root file system on /dev/sda4 requirs a manual fsck
It then ends at (iniramfs)

I don't know how to do a manual fsck

System will boot into 13.4.  If done in safe mode fsck runs OK with no warning.  However Update boot loader causes a lock up

Is there a way to recover?

Comment: Did you look up how to manually run fsck? Any search engine will tell you.

Comment: I don't think the issue is something `fsck` would fix anyway. Try booting with your Live USB and run boot-repair: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104855/how-to-make-grub-menu-appear-instead-grub-minimal-bash-like-in-booting/1105737#1105737

Comment: Also look up how to run a SMART test on the disk. A thoroughly devastated filesystem is very rare, and can be caused by hardware failure among other rare possibilities.

Comment: I did not realize fsck could be run from a Live USB.  It ran with no comments.  Boot Repair took a very long time to run but then failed to complete, twice.  The option for 18.04 has disappeared from the boot menu and 13.04 will no longer boot even in safe mode.  SMART test at first hung at 90% pending but later failed for Read Error Rate, Spinup Time, Reallocated Sector Count, Seek Error Rate and Spinup Retry Count.  Is there anything else to try or does this mean failed hard drive?