# Booting multiple copies of Windows via Grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, uefi

please check out how my SSD is structured, note "DEV" is Windows 10, and "DAW" is also another Windows 10:

```
nvme0n1                                                                          
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat   UEFI      D4F4-1F7A                             871.3M     8% /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 swap             b18a8de1-5fe2-413b-8605-813c5baa77c0             [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p3 ext4   UBUNTU    77018d89-077f-4076-9f2f-ba385addce9b  124.5G     8% /
├─nvme0n1p4 apfs             775b62e8-2e49-45d4-8460-46c7c8a79859                
├─nvme0n1p5 ntfs   DEV       EA3414BA34148C27                                    
├─nvme0n1p6 ntfs   DAW       7C8473EE8473A8F2                                    
└─nvme0n1p7
```

I can boot one of these Windows OSs from grub 2, however I want to boot both copies of Windows from GRUB, the easiest way to explain my issue is post my GRUB config file complete with comments, basically I get NTLR errors, any ideas how I can resolve?

Thanks!

```
# This entry works fine but only boots Windows on one partition.
# I need to boot the second Windows partition as well. Hence new boot entries below.
    # Note this is the only thing detected with sudo os-prober:

    menuentry "DAW - Windows 10" --class windows --class os {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod fat
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root D4F4-1F7A
        chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
    }

# The entry produces...
# error: file '/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ntldr.mod' not found.
# error: can't find 'ntldr'
    menuentry "DEV - Windows 10" {
        insmod ntfs
        insmod ntldr
        insmod part_msdos
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root EA3414BA34148C27
        ntldr /bootmgr                         
    }

#This entry produces...
#error: file '/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ntldr.mod' not found.
#error: can't find 'ntldr'
    menuentry "DAW - Windows 10" {
        insmod ntfs
        insmod ntldr
        insmod part_msdos
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 7C8473EE8473A8F2
        ntldr /bootmgr                         
    }
```

Comment: `ntldr` does not exists in EFI boot

Comment: The first entry uses:
chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi

How will it identify which windows OS to boot (there are two of them)? Currently it only boots one.

I want two entries in the Ubuntu menu, one for each Windows install.

Comment: BIOS boot? If so you have to have boot files in each Windows install and each has to be in a primary NTFS partition, otherwise not directly bootable. A user who installed two windows & it worked to boot from grub directly
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1271600

Comment: Did you try boot-repair yet?: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104855/how-to-make-grub-menu-appear-instead-grub-minimal-bash-like-in-booting/1105737#1105737

Comment: Windows dual boot works without Ubuntu via it's own boot loader so Windows does not need repairing.

Let me rephrase the question perhaps

***
    menuentry "DAW - Windows 10" --class windows --class os {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod fat
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root D4F4-1F7A
        chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
    }
***
This works. How do I boot into DEV Windows partition? This is NOT MBR this is GPT.

Thanks