# How can I uninstall another version of Ubuntu I installed 'along side' an existing Ubuntu install?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uninstall

I put in a USB ISO of a different Ubuntu version and thought I would try the 'Install Along Side' option. Now I want to uninstall it and have my original Ubuntu start up without the grub menu.

I installed `gparted` and read a few similar 'Ask Ubuntu' Q&As but I'm not sure what to do.
I know even if I delete the partitions, (is this what I should do?) that the original Ubuntu is not going to boot for anything because of a similar experience. So, there's a grub file that needs to be moved or changed? I looked inside boot of the Ubuntu install I want to uninstall and there was a grub file that had a note 'do not edit this file'.

I also tried OS Uninstaller and after trying to remove it I got a non-descript error message.

- The Ubuntu I want to keep is Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
- The Ubuntu I want to delete is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

If you'd like me to provide more information please comment and I will update.
Thank you.

Comment: You haven't provided releases of Ubuntu, but if you boot version you want to keep, make it own the MBR/grub (via `grub-install` with appropriate parameter) then you can delete the unwanted partitions, and finally `update-grub` so it can detect the other version no longer exists & adjusts the grub menu to match that.  *You haven't provided details of uEFI or MBR boot, nor if any other OSes are involved so this is more generic advice you can adjust for things I'm not aware of*

Comment: Usually, you just remove the unneeded partitions, recover grub if necessary, ...and done. Search for howto reinstall grub, which is not a file.

Comment: After playing with OS Uninstaller again and doing a restart I can't get any version of Ubuntu to start. Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS was the version I wanted to keep. The other version, I believe was just Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Don't ask why I installed it. Anyways. I just get a grub screen with the command prompt when I boot on that disk.

Comment: Sounds like you should use `boot-repair`:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104855/how-to-make-grub-menu-appear-instead-grub-minimal-bash-like-in-booting/1105737#1105737

Comment: "Sounds like you should use boot-repair" I won't be able to get back into that drive unless I install yet another Ubuntu version on that drive.

Comment: You run Boot-Repair from the Ubuntu live installer. You add the ppa, install & run the program. It normally defaults to first install it finds, but you can use advanced mode and choose which install to reinstall grub.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: "You run Boot-Repair from the Ubuntu live installer." I'll do that next time. I ended up re-installing and wiping the drive :(