# Minimal BASH like line editing is supported GRUB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, bash, uefi

When I start my PC, I get the error message:

```
Minimal bash like line editing is supported  ...
```

I tried to fix GRUB using [this](https://itsfoss.com/fix-minimal-bash-line-editing-supported-grub-error-linux/) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104855/how-to-make-grub-menu-appear-instead-grub-minimal-bash-like-in-booting), but the error is still there.

When I tried this command `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi` output was:

```
mount: mnt/boot/efi: Can't read the super block
```

I used [boot-repair method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7OkN.png), but I did not find the recommended repair method.

I don't have important files in Ubuntu so I don't have any problem if I loose the data in Ubuntu.

Here are my [partition details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndWZT.png).

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: all i did was type in 'exit' and hit enter... then I was able to bring up grub as normal.

Comment: I tried most of the solution given online but issue was not resolved. I had dual boot with windows and I start using windows after some time my hard disk currupt and i had to replace my hard disk now I don't have any issue