# Linux dual-boot fails unless open bios first

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I'm having a problem with a linux/windows dual boot system.  If power on the system or do a system restart, my grub menu disappears and I am left just at this Grub screen:

[image]

However, if I boot and open the bios....and don't change anything, just exit...It works...

[image]

[image]

I'm at the limits of linux-fu so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**** Update ****

I've run

```
sudo update-grub
```

and no effect.  Here is the contents of my /etc/default/grub file:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="10"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE="640x480"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
~
```

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details.

Comment: Thanks @guiverc, OS is Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

Comment: Can you edit the post to provide your contents of `/etc/defaults/grub`

Comment: The normal grub install install two sets of bootloaders, one set under /EFI/ubuntu (named shimx64.efi and grubx64.efi) along with a stub grub.cfg that brings in the root's maintained /boot/grub/grub.cfg, and the other set under /EFI/Boot (named bootx64.efi and grubx64.efi (no grub.cfg and if no secure boot, the grubx64.efi is the bootx64.efi. Not sure what happens these days if another grub.cfg is present in /EFI/Boot, but take a look, Can you successfully boot the device (via the EFI boot menu at power-up?

Comment: This might help: [How to make grub menu appear instead grub minimal bash-like in booting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104855/how-to-make-grub-menu-appear-instead-grub-minimal-bash-like-in-booting/1105737#1105737)

Comment: The limit should be windows-fu

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Thanks.  It is now fixed and it was a two step process.  I ran boot-repair.  Then my system started booting directly into Ubuntu (no grub menu).  Then I ran update-grub as mentioned below and got my grub menu back.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Thye easiest way to fix would likely be simply running the following command:

```
$  sudo update-grub
```

This obviously runs the grub updater. That should reset so thyat the intended defaults are restored.

If this does not work, another way of getting the Grub menu to show on startup is to explicitly define the behaviour. In the file `/etc/defaults/grub` there may or may not be a line that reads

```
$  GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT= N
```

where `N` is a number. This defines that the grub menu should be displayed on boot for exactly `N` seconds. Once that iime elapses, the default will be loaded.

The behavior that you described is as if it were set to zero. Check the `defaults/grub` to see if the line

```
$  GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
```

is present. if it is, then change the `0` to a number between 45 and 90 (or however many seconds you prefer it to be displayed for.) After it is changed, save the file and reboot. Remember, if you pull it up in a command line editor like `nvim`, `nano`, `emacs`, or `gedit`, you will need to use `sudo` or else you will not be able to save.

Comment: Changing the line `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` will only be effective if there is no "#" in front of it.  The '#' turns the command into simple text ( called commenting out) which is ignored by the processes that call/read the file.  I am running 20.04 and these lines are uncommented (no '#' sign in front of them) in `/etc/default/grub`- `GRUB_DEFAULT=0`  `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden`  `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0` Plus three remaining lines.  I didn't alter this file so these are the defaults from the installation.

Comment: Yea my bad. Its a double typo. I copied / pasted for the second instance. TY for pointing it out! It can also be interpreted as the prompt for Root user.. Should I go with that as my excuse? XD really, though, ty..

Comment: I just wanted to make that clear so that other users don't copy as written then wonder why it didn't fix anything.  What they are doing is editing a file, not running a command.  They should also ignore the "$" lol.  No worries Nate T.

Comment: @NateT, See my comment above.  I had to run boot-repair first and then the update-grub worked.  Also worth noting that on my system the grub config is at /etc/default/grub (vs. defaults).  But thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. I'm glad things worked out for you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I have an answer for that But I had a kind of similar issue but I got it fixed by using REfind as my boot manager instead and then went into the bios and made it the first in the boot order then went back to my xubuntu and made it first in the uefi boot order then went back again to windows and used an efi tool editor to make it again the first in the boot order and at the last I did another bios boot order change to make it at top again, then it just worked fine
I am sure this might not help but I thought it might be related