# Having to set root and prefix every time I boot on grub 2 "minimal bash like editing"

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, bios

I tried the alternative method shown [here](https://itsfoss.com/fix-minimal-bash-line-editing-supported-grub-error-linux/) using `boot-repair` after the system didn't detect at all the linux bootloader (only windows option and the disc only (which I don't know why it appears) were in the bios boot order options and in the boot menu). Now the BIOS detects the bootloader (ubuntu is added to the list), but in this minimal bash mode.

I have to type the following lines to make it show the usual splash screen, just as I customised it:

```
set root=(hd0, gpt5) (this is my root partition)
set prefix=(hd0, gpt5)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

Why do I have to type this every time I boot? How can I solve it? I also tried to use boot-repair to reinstall grub completly ticking the purge grub option, but it still doesn't work

**EDIT: Requested info**

```
~ ❯ sudo parted -l


Model: SSSTC CL1-4D512 (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 512GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  274MB  273MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot, esp
 2      274MB   290MB  16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 3      290MB   262GB  262GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 5      262GB   510GB  248GB   ext4         (Unlabelled root)
 6      510GB   511GB  629MB   fat32        (Unlabelled boot)                                      boot, esp
 4      511GB   512GB  1049MB  ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, diag
```

```
sudo cat /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg
cat: /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg: No such file or directory (this doesn't look good)
```

```
~ ❯ sudo ls /boot/efi/EFI
BOOT  Linux  pop  Pop_OS-4ce634ae-abfa-41e3-8b20-28dabe16a83d  systemd
```

```
~ ❯ sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p6 /mnt

~ ❯ sudo ls -R /mnt
/mnt:
 BootInfo   boot-sav   EFI   loader  'System Volume Information'

/mnt/BootInfo:
FD

/mnt/BootInfo/FD:
sda

/mnt/BootInfo/FD/sda:

/mnt/boot-sav:
nvme0n1p1  nvme0n1p3  nvme0n1p4

/mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1:

/mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3:

/mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4:

/mnt/EFI:
BOOT  Linux  pop  Pop_OS-4ce634ae-abfa-41e3-8b20-28dabe16a83d  systemd

/mnt/EFI/BOOT:
bkpbootx64.efi  bootx64.efi  fbx64.efi  grubx64.efi  mmx64.efi

/mnt/EFI/Linux:

/mnt/EFI/pop:
BOOTX64.CSV  grub.cfg  grubx64.efi  mmx64.efi  shimx64.efi

/mnt/EFI/Pop_OS-4ce634ae-abfa-41e3-8b20-28dabe16a83d:
cmdline  initrd.img  initrd.img-previous  vmlinuz.efi  vmlinuz-previous.efi

/mnt/EFI/systemd:
systemd-bootx64.efi

/mnt/loader:
entries  loader.conf  random-seed

/mnt/loader/entries:
Pop_OS-current.conf  Pop_OS-oldkern.conf

'/mnt/System Volume Information':
```

```
~ ❯ sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt

~ ❯ sudo ls -R /mnt
/mnt:
'$RECYCLE.BIN'   BOOT   EFI  'System Volume Information'

'/mnt/$RECYCLE.BIN':
desktop.ini

/mnt/BOOT:
BOOT.SDI

/mnt/EFI:
Boot  Microsoft  pop  UpdateCapsule

/mnt/EFI/Boot:
bkpbootx64.efi  bootx64.efi  fbx64.efi  grubx64.efi  mmx64.efi

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft:
Boot  Recovery

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot:
BCD   bootmgfw.efi  da-DK  es-ES  fr-CA  ja-JP       kd_02_15b3.dll  kd_07_1415.dll   lt-LT        pl-PL      ro-RO       sv-SE        zh-TW
BCD.LOG   bootmgr.efi   de-DE  es-MX  fr-FR  kd_02_10df.dll  kd_02_1969.dll  kd_0C_8086.dll   lv-LV        pt-BR      ru-RU       tr-TR
BCD.LOG1  BOOTSTAT.DAT  el-GR  et-EE  hr-HR  kd_02_10ec.dll  kd_02_19a2.dll  kdnet_uart16550.dll  memtest.efi  pt-PT      sk-SK       uk-UA
BCD.LOG2  boot.stl  en-GB  fi-FI  hu-HU  kd_02_1137.dll  kd_02_1af4.dll  kdstub.dll       nb-NO        qps-ploc   sl-SI       winsipolicy.p7b
bg-BG     cs-CZ     en-US  Fonts  it-IT  kd_02_14e4.dll  kd_02_8086.dll  ko-KR        nl-NL        Resources  sr-Latn-RS  zh-CN

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bg-BG:
bootmgfw.efi.mui  bootmgr.efi.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/cs-CZ:
bootmgfw.efi.mui  bootmgr.efi.mui  memtest.efi.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/da-DK:
bootmgfw.efi.mui  bootmgr.efi.mui  memtest.efi.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/de-DE:
bootmgfw.efi.mui  bootmgr.efi.mui  memtest.efi.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/el-GR:
bootmgfw.efi.mui  bootmgr.efi.mui  memtest.efi.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/en-GB:
bootmgfw.efi.mui  bootmgr.efi.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/en-US:
bootmgfw.efi.mui  bootmgr.efi.mui  memtest.efi.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/es-ES:
bootmgfw.efi.mui  bootmgr.efi.mui  memtest.efi.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/es-MX:
bootmgfw.efi.mui  bootmgr.efi.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/et-EE:
bootmgfw.efi.mui  bootmgr.efi.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/fi-FI:
bootmgfw.efi.mui  bootmgr.efi.mui  memtest.efi.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/Fonts:
chs_boot.ttf  jpn_boot.ttf  malgun_boot.ttf   meiryo_boot.ttf   msjh_boot.ttf   msyh_boot.ttf   segmono_boot.ttf   segoe_slboot.ttf
cht_boot.ttf  kor_boot.ttf  malgunn_boot.ttf  meiryon_boot.ttf  msjhn_boot.ttf  msyhn_boot.ttf  segoen_slboot.ttf  wgl4_boot.ttf

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/fr-CA:
bootmgfw.efi.mui  bootmgr.efi.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/fr-FR:
bootmgfw.efi.mui  bootmgr.efi.mui  memtest.efi.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/hr-HR:
bootmgfw.efi.mui  bootmgr.efi.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/hu-HU:
bootmgfw.efi.mui  bootmgr.efi.mui  memtest.efi.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/it-IT:
bootmgfw.efi.mui  bootmgr.efi.mui  memtest.efi.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/ja-JP:
bootmgfw.efi.mui  bootmgr.efi.mui  memtest.efi.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/ko-KR:
bootmgfw.efi.mui  bootmgr.efi.mui  memtest.efi.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/lt-LT:
bootmgfw.efi.mui  bootmgr.efi.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/lv-LV:
bootmgfw.efi.mui  bootmgr.efi.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/nb-NO:
bootmgfw.efi.mui  bootmgr.efi.mui  memtest.efi.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/nl-NL:
bootmgfw.efi.mui  bootmgr.efi.mui  memtest.efi.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/pl-PL:
bootmgfw.efi.mui  bootmgr.efi.mui  memtest.efi.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/pt-BR:
bootmgfw.efi.mui  bootmgr.efi.mui  memtest.efi.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/pt-PT:
bootmgfw.efi.mui  bootmgr.efi.mui  memtest.efi.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/qps-ploc:
memtest.efi.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/Resources:
bootres.dll  en-US

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/Resources/en-US:
bootres.dll.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/ro-RO:
bootmgfw.efi.mui  bootmgr.efi.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/ru-RU:
bootmgfw.efi.mui  bootmgr.efi.mui  memtest.efi.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/sk-SK:
bootmgfw.efi.mui  bootmgr.efi.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/sl-SI:
bootmgfw.efi.mui  bootmgr.efi.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/sr-Latn-RS:
bootmgfw.efi.mui  bootmgr.efi.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/sv-SE:
bootmgfw.efi.mui  bootmgr.efi.mui  memtest.efi.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/tr-TR:
bootmgfw.efi.mui  bootmgr.efi.mui  memtest.efi.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/uk-UA:
bootmgfw.efi.mui  bootmgr.efi.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/zh-CN:
bootmgfw.efi.mui  bootmgr.efi.mui  memtest.efi.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/zh-TW:
bootmgfw.efi.mui  bootmgr.efi.mui  memtest.efi.mui

/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Recovery:
BCD  BCD.LOG  BCD.LOG1  BCD.LOG2

/mnt/EFI/pop:
grubx64.efi  shimx64.efi

/mnt/EFI/UpdateCapsule:
CapsuleUpdateFile1000.bin

'/mnt/System Volume Information':
AadRecoveryPasswordDelete  ClientRecoveryPasswordRotation  IndexerVolumeGuid  WPSettings.dat

'/mnt/System Volume Information/AadRecoveryPasswordDelete':

'/mnt/System Volume Information/ClientRecoveryPasswordRotation':
```

**UPDATE:** Nevermind, the computer died again (not because of me, the motherboard broke for the second time and I hope I can get the whole thing replaced). Thanks to the ones that tried to help me

Comment: Can you post link to your `boot-repair` log?

Comment: It didn't leave anything. The link was `https://paste2.org/` or am I looking for something else?

Comment: Yes the link is incorrect. Try boot repair again and then copy and paste the link into your question.

Comment: I tried again and got the same link, which takes me to a page where I could paste a code, but I have no codes. I clicked 'yes' when it asked me to upload the logs to a paste bin. Do you know why isn't giving me any logs?

Comment: When you look at this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104855/how-to-make-grub-menu-appear-instead-grub-minimal-bash-like-in-booting/1105737#1105737 Make sure you click the second option to get a report.

Comment: You mean creating bootinfo summary? It still gives me this message: Please write on a paper the following URL:
https://paste2.org/


If you are experiencing boot issues, indicate this URL to people who help you. For example on forums or via email.

Comment: There is a problem. Because the link is missing `/` followed by a 6 or 7 digit number (or something like that).

Comment: I know, that's why I thinks this is so weird. I'll try to reinstall boot repair when I have the time and see how it goes. I will comment here when I get any results

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't fixed grub yet. All you've done so far is allowed yourself to boot up from the grub terminal. You need to type the following from terminal once you have fully booted up:

```
sudo update-grub

sudo grub-install /dev/sda

shutdown -r now
```

Comment: Boot-repair doesn't always work. Did you get an error with *grub-install* command? Run `ls /dev/nvme*` and check that *nvme0n1* exists. I think it's **nvme0n1** that has to be used in the grub-install command for an M.2 SSD

Comment: Report would show us details, so we can make better suggestions. But issue is that you are booting with an old install of grub, but have updated system and installed grub somewhere else. system is booting from old version of grub. May be that Windows is UEFi and Ubuntu BIOS or if now both UEFI, you have old BIOS grub installed? If UEFI system be sure to always boot in UEFI boot mode. Or you installed grub in BIOS boot mode without bios_grub partition. Or ???

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'SYSTEM_DRV' partition. Not something I'm familiar with. nvme0n1 is the notation for your M.2 drive, just like sda is notation for an HDD, and in the latter case I would re-install grub with `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` as I've done many times before. I think to get a clearer picture, please post output of `sudo parted -l` and `sudo gedit /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg` into your question.

Comment: Your efi partition is nvmeon1p1, and that should contain efi boot files for Win and Ubuntu. Nvmeon1p6 is also an efi partition. Maybe that's where your Ubuntu efi files are. For some reason it's showing up weirdly in the *parted* command. First we need to see what's in nvmeon1p1, So if you do sudo ls /boot/efi/EFI, what folders are shown? Also mount nvmeon1p6 - sudo mount /dev/nvmeon1p6 /mnt. Then need output for sudo ls -R /mnt.

Comment: Your efi is showing Pop as your Linux system. Are you using Ubuntu or Linux Pop, because this is supposed to be a forum for Ubuntu, not dists based on Ubuntu?  Having said that, you really just need 1 ESP, rather than the 2 you have. You have 2 pop files and 2 boot loaders, namely grub and systemd-boot, ie it's a mess. I'm going to suggest you just use nvmeon1p1 as your EFI and delete  nvmeon1p6 **eventually**. I'll get back to you about that later.

Comment: SInce the installer asked for a boot partition bigger than 500MB I created a new one (the original one was nvme0n1p1 with the windows boot loader). I guess I can't resize nvme0n1p1 so I should keep the other one instead and move the windows boot files to that one. And yes, its pop os. I though it would be no problem since its just ubuntu with some gnome extensions and minor changes, or that's what I think it is. Sorry about that

Comment: I'll get back to you later on. All responses by me will now be through 'Answer', which I'll keep editing where necessary, as comments are getting too numerous. Meanwhile can you tidy up your question and delete nvme0n1p1 output from */mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bg-BG:* to */mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/zh-TW:* as they're irrelevant language options. Also delete your messages to me except your last 2.