# When I reboot my Dell laptop (which only has Ubuntu), I get stuck on this screen that says "Minimal BASH-like line editing..."

Tags: boot, grub2, dell

I have been using a Dell laptop which has Ubuntu for over a year now. Today, when I opened it, I'm stuck on this screen with this message:

```
GNU GRUB version 2.04
Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.
grub>
```

Now, I have tried multiple solutions from the web, StackOverflow, Askubuntu, etc. but nothing solves it.

Now, I don't know what the issue is but these are some of the roadblocks I faced:

1. If I type

   ls /

all I get is

```
backenddb.xml
```

which is very different than what is here - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting#Search_.26_Set

2. A lot of solutions mention to "set root" and "set prefix" based on where the grub.cfg file is. I think I had found and done this. A little digging showed that the grub.cfg file is at:

   ls (hd0,1)/efi/ubuntu/

Output was:

```
grubx64.efi shimx64.efi mx64.efi bootx64.csv grub.cfg
```

So I tried this:

```
grub> set root=(hd0,1)
grub> set prefix=(hd0,1)/efi/ubuntu
grub> insmod normal
grub> normal
```

After this, the screen got cleared and it just left me with a grub> on the top-left. I don't know what to do after this since I didn't find anything where this happened.

I don't really know what else to do. Please help me.

Update 1:

Used a live USB to finally access Ubuntu and open the terminal. Then I tried using Boot Repair, but I didn't get the "Recommended Repair" option. The only option I have is to consult online forums. Here, is my pastebin link - https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/bgtJPTq8wk/

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Start by booting from a live media and seeing if the hardware will run that. ONE possibility is the hard drive is the issue. What did you do just before it went like this? Updates new software installed?

Comment: Does it solve your problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104855/how-to-make-grub-menu-appear-instead-grub-minimal-bash-like-in-booting  ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make grub menu appear instead grub minimal bash-like in booting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104855/how-to-make-grub-menu-appear-instead-grub-minimal-bash-like-in-booting)

Comment: This didn't solve my solution, but I tried using a live USB and downloaded boot-repair. It didn't give me the recommended option which is where I'm stuck at now. This is my BootInfo Summary - https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/bgtJPTq8wk/