# Fresh install, grub "Minimal BASH-like..."

Tags: boot, grub2, thinkpad

I've just installed Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS on my Thinkpad L14 Gen 1 AMD (no dual-boot). Both Secure boot and CSM are off in the Bios settings. After installation, when I try to boot, I get to a grub screen saying "Minimal BASH-like editing is supported".

I've tried following the most common guides to fix this problem. Tried re-installing multiple times as well.

The following commands get me to the OS itself:

```
set root=(hd0,gpt2)
configfile (hd0,gpt2)/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

and

```
set root=(hd0,gpt2)
set prefix=(hd0,gpt2)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

After running the second set of commands and running `sudo grub-install \dev\nvme0np1` followed by `sudo update-grub` did not fix the problem (after rebooting).

Runnig `ls` inside the grub screen returns me this:

```
(proc) (hd0) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1)
```

Is there anything I'm missing on how to fix my grub?

UPDATE: Ubuntu 18.04.6 boots with no problems after installation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make grub menu appear instead grub minimal bash-like in booting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104855/how-to-make-grub-menu-appear-instead-grub-minimal-bash-like-in-booting)

Comment: Hello. If the other OS version runs fine one possible issue is bad ISO. Did you verify the ISO after downloading and the make of the live media?