# Minimal bash like line editing... error

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, bash

I installed ubuntu in my computer a few weeks ago, and I was using it through dual-boot (I have Windows 11 and Ubuntu) without any problems. A few hours ago, I turned on my computer and this error appeared:

"Minimal BASH like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions"

I changed the boot order from F2 and I put Windows first, and now my computer run Windows without display the GRUB screen. I changed again the boot order and the same error still displaying.

Also I've tried connecting my USB with the Linux ISO but when I open the Boot Menu (F12), I have only 2 options: Ubuntu and Windows, not my USB device. If I choose Ubuntu, the same error is displayed again.

Also I've tried entering "exit" but the same black screen is displayed again.

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: You've not provided us with many details; we don't know anything about what Ubuntu product (Ubuntu Core, Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop etc), nor what release of that product was installed, thus limiting what we can offer. You mention a Linux ISO but without details again (*and reference to Linux and not Ubuntu implies it wasn't a Ubuntu system to me*) which is where I'd start (*ie. Ubuntu ISO in live mode to explore*) but without specifics we'd be guessing, thus are unlikely to respond.  Try and be specific with details I'll suggest.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make grub menu appear instead grub minimal bash-like in booting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104855/how-to-make-grub-menu-appear-instead-grub-minimal-bash-like-in-booting)