# Booting to windows with windows boot manager or bootmgfw.efi

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

Yesterday I have managed to successfully install and configure Ubuntu 18.04 LTS as a second operating system on my PC.Everything works fine,however there is one thing that confuses me:
In the GRUB,among all other boot options I have:

1. Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi.
2. Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/...)

Essentially both of them successfully boot Windows 10,so my questions are:
Are there any differences between this two options in terms of operations or functionality of Windows 10? What are the differences between these options?

Comment: Good question. In my case I had over 5 Windows boot options in Grub many of which did **not** work: https://askubuntu.com/questions/938633/boot-repair-created-too-many-grub-menu-entries-for-windows/1022700#1022700

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix the extra GRUB boot choices come from having run boot-repair. It puts a file in `/etc/grub.d/25_custom` that adds the extras. Just delete that file and `sudo update-grub`, and your GRUB menu will look nice again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/1261860/difference-between-bootmgr-efi-and-bootmgfw-efi) explains the difference quite clearly. If both work, there should be no difference between booting with the .efi file vs. using bootmgr from a user's perspective.