# Installed Ubuntu using the dual boot, but can't boot Windows. How to recover Windows?

Tags: boot, dual-boot

My files seem fine, but I have no idea what happened to Windows OS. Here is my [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/pRMQPaSF) information on the boot. I tried reinstalling grub, and going through diskpart, didn't seem to work. How do I avoid this mistake in future?

output from `gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="Windows Boot UEFI loader"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd1,gpt5'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt5  057c72d1-5cbc-46b7-af0d-1cd9cb64f617
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 057c72d1-5cbc-46b7-af0d-1cd9cb64f617
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=hidden
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  elif sleep --interruptible 10 ; then
    set timeout=0
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30,0; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=1
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-057c72d1-5cbc-46b7-af0d-1cd9cb64f617' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd1,gpt5'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt5  057c72d1-5cbc-46b7-af0d-1cd9cb64f617
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 057c72d1-5cbc-46b7-af0d-1cd9cb64f617
    fi
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-23-generic root=UUID=057c72d1-5cbc-46b7-af0d-1cd9cb64f617 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-23-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-057c72d1-5cbc-46b7-af0d-1cd9cb64f617' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.0.0-23-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.0.0-23-generic-advanced-057c72d1-5cbc-46b7-af0d-1cd9cb64f617' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd1,gpt5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt5  057c72d1-5cbc-46b7-af0d-1cd9cb64f617
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 057c72d1-5cbc-46b7-af0d-1cd9cb64f617
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.0.0-23-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-23-generic root=UUID=057c72d1-5cbc-46b7-af0d-1cd9cb64f617 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-23-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.0.0-23-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.0.0-23-generic-recovery-057c72d1-5cbc-46b7-af0d-1cd9cb64f617' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd1,gpt5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt5  057c72d1-5cbc-46b7-af0d-1cd9cb64f617
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 057c72d1-5cbc-46b7-af0d-1cd9cb64f617
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.0.0-23-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-23-generic root=UUID=057c72d1-5cbc-46b7-af0d-1cd9cb64f617 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-23-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.18.0-15-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.18.0-15-generic-advanced-057c72d1-5cbc-46b7-af0d-1cd9cb64f617' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd1,gpt5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt5  057c72d1-5cbc-46b7-af0d-1cd9cb64f617
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 057c72d1-5cbc-46b7-af0d-1cd9cb64f617
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.18.0-15-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-15-generic root=UUID=057c72d1-5cbc-46b7-af0d-1cd9cb64f617 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-15-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.18.0-15-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.18.0-15-generic-recovery-057c72d1-5cbc-46b7-af0d-1cd9cb64f617' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd1,gpt5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt5  057c72d1-5cbc-46b7-af0d-1cd9cb64f617
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 057c72d1-5cbc-46b7-af0d-1cd9cb64f617
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.18.0-15-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-15-generic root=UUID=057c72d1-5cbc-46b7-af0d-1cd9cb64f617 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-15-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/25_custom ###


### END /etc/grub.d/25_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
menuentry 'System setup' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
    fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

Comment: Your pastebin requires me to register with another website (Ubuntu One). Shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Thank you, should be fixed.

Comment: The photos you posted are irrelevant so please edit them out. Can you explain exactly what you mean by '*what happened to Windows* '? Diskpart is a Windows prog so you must have booted into it. Need to confirm which Windows OS you are using and if it is installed on sdb3. Is all your data on sda2? If not what is on there? Have you backed up all data? Need make/model of computer?

Comment: You have UEFI Windows entries, but the Windows partition sdb3 has old BIOS boot files boot.ini & bootmgr. Did you copy an old install onto drive, but have a newer copy now not shown? Can you directly boot Windows from UEFI, not from grub? Boot-Repair also adds a lot of grub menu entries in 25_custom, you may want to houseclean. https://askubuntu.com/questions/938633/boot-repair-created-too-many-grub-menu-entries-for-windows/1022700#1022700

Comment: @PaulBenson So after I installed Ubuntu, grub loaded with a windows menu; however, it couldn't boot into the windows. I tried different solutions, and it only loads me into Advanced Boot mode with trouble shoot and power off. I am using Windows 10 OS, I got to Diskpart through console in the advanced boot menu. Windows should be installed in sdb3, but I am not sure, since it takes the most data I assume it is. Most data is on stb3, but another majority is in sda2. I don't think I backed up my data, and the model of my computer is HP:750-171.

Comment: @oldfred Sorry, are you talking about an old install of Ubuntu? If you are, then I think so, because I had to download updates. I think I tried loading windows through uefi, but it didn't work through advanced boot option menu. If I am not mistaken...

Comment: Not old install of Ubuntu but of Windows. An UEFI install of Windows does not have boot.ini, that is BIOS boot. And you can only boot a BIOS Windows from a MBR(msdos) partitioned drive. But you have Windows UEFI boot entries from a Windows install that is not shown anywhere?? And an UEFI install of Windows only boots from a gpt partitioned drive. You cannot have both a BIOS boot Windows and UEFI boot Windows on same drive.

Comment: @Daler Pastebin shows a mess re Windows. L.64 shows 2 Win booting files which became redundant since XP. W10 cannot use those to boot. You also have Windows MRP duplicated on sda1 - l.100 & l.121. Please post output for command `grep -A9 -i 'windows' /boot/grub/grub.cfg` into your question.

Comment: @oldfred Is this due to the improper installation of Ubuntu and improper partition? From what I understand, there is a contradiction in the system in which my system is trying to boot windows with incompatible firmware. So does it mean that (hard drive?) partition created said contradiction in which the incompatible firmware of Windows is present? I am not sure how to approach solving this problem as I am pretty new to Ubuntu.

Comment: You need to understand Windows to know if you forced change to drive. But since you have Windows UEFI entries, you must at some point had an UEFI install of Windows. Perhaps you erased your working Windows? But boot files in NTFS partition are for old style. BIOS & UEFI Windows partitions, note system has totally different format  & meaning between BIOS & UEFI
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898504%28v=vs.85%29.aspx & 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations

Comment: @PaulBenson In the grub, for Windows, it prints "Windows (UEFI)" after cleanup of the grub. Whenever I boot it, it places me into a keyboard layout menu, into Advanced options menu to interact with windows.

Comment: @Daler. What you posted shows that you have no menu entry for Windows, and that the current grub file does not correlate, as that output does not exist in the Pastebin grub file. When the boot grub page comes up, what exactly is printed for a Windows entry? Were you booted unto Ubuntu when you ran that command (not Live Ubuntu)?

Comment: OK. I'll need to see your current grub file as that output makes no sense. Delete the output from question and instead copy and paste output from `gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Comment: @PaulBenson updated the output.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling windows is I think the only solution, however, after that you have to re-install ubnutu properly, using one of the tutorials on youtube.