# After upgrading dual boot system from 19.04 to 19.10, unable to boot into Windows from grub menu

Tags: boot, grub2, windows, uefi, 19.10

After upgrade to 19.10 on my dual boot system I am unable to boot into Windows.

If I change boot order in the BIOS and put windows boot manager first I can boot into Windows no problem.

However... from the grub menu when I select Windows boot manager the screen flashes and I'm back at the grub menu. So I do see Windows as an option in grub, it just doesn't boot.

I used `sudo grub-update`

and `boot-repair`

here is the log:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rJPfP9WwSs/

Comment: [Chrismile](https://askubuntu.com/users/1007465/chrismile) deleted answer converted to comment: *"I can confirm that this is NOT a duplicate of the linked post (sorry that I can't use the comment functionality for stating this, as it is disabled for new users). This is definitely a bug in the upgrade process from Ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10 and the answer in the linked post does not fix this problem."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug in Grub 2.04, which is shipped by Ubuntu 19.10.

See:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1839317
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1845289

You might consider either downgrading the version of Grub on your system or waiting for a fixed version.

Comment: This appears to be my issue. Just going to wait it out as I rarely use windows so it isn't much of an inconvenience to me, I'll just swap boot order when I need to get in. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The instructions on `boot-repair` report tell you to boot into Windows (as you do now by changing boot order) and then:

> ```
> For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
> bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
> ```

Do this from Windows and then if it doesn't work revise your question with current status / new issues.

---

Also note boot-repair created 7 custom entries to boot Windows and Ubuntu from UEFI. In my experience they won't all work. After you fix the booting issues see this answer:

- [Boot-Repair created too many grub menu entries for Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938633/boot-repair-created-too-many-grub-menu-entries-for-windows/1022700#1022700)

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the issue for me. My bootmgr path was previously using grubx64.efi. I'm a little surprised this worked, since if there were an issue with SecureBoot I'd expect Grub not to load at all :shrug: