# How to switch between windows and Ubuntu without configuring?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I have both Ubuntu 19 and Windows 7 installed on my computer. I use both frequently.
When I boot to Ubuntu everything is great. Loads right up.
When I then boot to Windows it's not very good.
First, I have to enter the BIOS and tell my PC which drive to boot and then I get the GRUB menu. If I don't it always boots Ubuntu. Shouldn't it default to the GRUB?
Then when it boots Windows it ALWAYS has to configure for a long time. Sometimes I need to restart it again to get it to load.
How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Your grub menu should contain an option to boot Windows. If it doesn't contain that option or that option doesn't work then run [boot-repair](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104855/how-to-make-grub-menu-appear-instead-grub-minimal-bash-like-in-booting/1105737#1105737):

Then check your boot-repair log to see if this is the problem:

- [After upgrading dual boot system from 19.04 to 19.10, unable to boot into Windows from grub menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182331/after-upgrading-dual-boot-system-from-19-04-to-19-10-unable-to-boot-into-window/1182429#1182429)