# Can't configure windows boot loader to choose between windows and Ubuntu during dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I have installed **Ubuntu 18.04** on a partition on the same HDD where my **Windows 10 Home (both are in UEFI)** is installed, but can't choose between the OSs to boot. It always boot Windows as default OS. How to fix this issue and fix the boot loader to choose between the OS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Answer (score 0):

I would use boot-repair as described here:

- [How to make grub menu appear instead grub minimal bash-like in booting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104855/how-to-make-grub-menu-appear-instead-grub-minimal-bash-like-in-booting/1105737#1105737)

**Note:** If you can't boot Ubuntu at all, use a Live USB to boot Ubuntu, select "Try before installing" and perform steps below.

---

After booting the hard way, open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and install [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Then type `boot-repair` and a menu will appear:

[image: boot-repair menu.png]

Select the recommended option.

If your system boots normally after recommended repair great. If not post the link to the problems reported.

---

#### Caveats

On some systems this annoyance can occur:

- [Boot-Repair created too many grub menu entries for Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938633/boot-repair-created-too-many-grub-menu-entries-for-windows/1022700#1022700)

If this happens to you, visit the link for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking, or double checking the bios settings to confirm  the boot settings on the drive. Depending on the  bios, it may be necessary to change the boot devices/or drive priority before grub will display the boot options at boot time. If something in the bios is not set properly, the system may default to booting straight into windows without displaying the grub menu first

Comment: I have checked the bios settings and changed to boot option to Ubuntu so that when it will boot it can find the grub boot loader. But still it boots into Windows instead. What should I do then (by the way I am using HP laptop)