# Grub customizer problem

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I had a dual boot set up with Windows/Ubuntu, but the Windows boot manager never opened up Ubuntu. I always had to go into the UEFI startup menu to go into Ubuntu, so I tried setting it to load that on startup through Grub Customizer. But, instead, it continues to load the Windows boot manager.

Now, when starting my computer, I press <kbd>F9</kbd> and it goes into the boot manager, select *Ubuntu* to start that up, but it loops back around to the UEFI startup menu.

I have no idea what to try nor do I want to try anything else in fear of doing something worse. I wish I could reset the Grub Customizer settings, but, without being able to load Ubuntu, I do not know how I could do that.

Is there any way to boot up into Ubuntu again instead of the UEFI startup menu or did I completely mess it up permanently?

Update: ran a report using "boot-repair" on a usb loaded copy of ubuntu.
here os the link to the report
Https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/dz8HJC82Nr/

Also, if i installed a permanent copy of ubuntu on a third partition, would i be able to download grub customizer again and change the settings that way back to booting normally? I tried downloading it on the usb copy of ubuntu but since its not an authorized user it wouldnt download nor would i be able to make changes to the computer settings

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can run `boot-repair` trial run (report only) and post the link to the report into your question. https://askubuntu.com/a/1194726/307523

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that. Follow up on this, would it be possible to reinstall grub customizer on the trial of ubuntu and change the settings from there?

Comment: I haven't used grub customizer but you can probably google that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem with my system. I installed Windows 10 first and left about 30% space on my 512GB SSD for Ubuntu. If you already created full partition when installing windows you can shrink it and create free space for Ubuntu.

Make sure to **disable the secure boot** in the UEFI BIOS when installing Ubuntu choose that free space.

Please **Disable Fast Startup** in Windows before installing Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks. I think ive given up at this point and installed a new ubuntu with the old one in a different partition. Im just going to try and save my data and get rid of the entire thing now.